# Distribute the values of one column into N columns

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have one column contain (1968) integer values (rows) how can separate these values into for example 5 columns?
Data in the column(inside csv file) something like this:

```
34
33
28
22
21
19
18
25
15
5
0
-8
-10
-19
-25
-39
-49
```

I need the output be in csv file and like this(The data is distributed on the required columns)

```
22  18  5   -10
21  25  0   -19
19  15  -8  -25
            -39
            -49
```

Comment: Can you provide a (short) sample input & the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can partition your data with `np.array_split` like so:

```
n_columns = 4 # Number of columns you want

data = [34, 33, 28, 22, 21, 19, 18, 25, 15, 5, 0, -8, -10, -19, -25, -39, -49]
data = np.array(data) # You already have your data
columns = np.array_split(data, n_columns, axis=0)
```

Then build a dataframe with `columns` and export it to a `csv` file with `to_csv` using `sep=';'` so that different columns are used inside your file, instead of entries being separated with a `,`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns).T
df.to_csv("data.csv", sep=';', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not achieve what I want, because I have data in a file in one column and I want to distribute this column into a number of columns, for example five columns!

Comment: Read your data first.

Comment: Yes, I did, I just read my file and remove ' ;', thanks!